# OnTriggerExit collision with TerrainCollider

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a digging mechanism in my game by setting heights of the terrainData.

Everything works fine, but I found a bug. As can be seen on attached image, I put a Collider as a Trigger to check whether the whole terrain from the Trigger area is removed. I check it in OnTriggerExit method.
It works, but when I left some terrain 'in the middle' (as image shows) and removed terrain only around the Trigger is says that there is no collision with Terrain Collider (but it should be!!)

Thanks!

[image: Collider in game]

Answer (score 0):

if your terrain has rigidbody in it will not detect collision because continous collision detection in terrain collider is not supported. one way to fix this is change terrain collider with box collider or remove rigidbody in terrain object.

Comment: My terrain doesn't have rigidbody - it seems to be illogical for me.
This blue object has Rigidbody (kinematic) because it is needed to the collision detection.